# function's local var not getting argument value

Tags: javascript, function, scope, arguments, var

This seems strange to me.  I have

```
var j = "x";
var k = "y";

function fun1 ( a, b) {
  var j = a;
  var k = b;
  console.log("this.j is:", this.j);
  console.log("this.k is:", this.k);
  this.j = a;
  this.k = b;
  return this.j + this.k;
};

console.log("j is ", j);
console.log("k is ", k);
console.log("fun1(3,4) is ", fun1(3,4));
console.log("j is ", j);
console.log("k is ", k);
console.log("fun1(2,7) is ", fun1(2,7));
console.log("j is ", j);
console.log("k is ", k);
```

When I run this in Node.js, I get:

```
j is  x
k is  y
this.j is: undefined
this.k is: undefined
fun1(3,4) is  7
j is  x
k is  y
this.j is: 3
this.k is: 4
fun1(2,7) is  9
j is  x
k is  y
```

Why aren't j and k being set to arguments a and b in the function when they are declared?  It just doesn't seem right that I have to do BOTH var j = a; AND this.j = a; !!  What am I doing wrong?

In node, the output properly shows that the j and k variables in global are not being clobbered by the local variables j and k in fun1.  When I run this in Chrome or Firefox, the global variables DO GET clobbered.  In other words I get

```
j is  x
k is  y
this.j is: undefined
this.k is: undefined
fun1(3,4) is  7
j is  3
k is  4
this.j is: 3
this.k is: 4
fun1(2,7) is  9
j is  2
k is  7
```

Why isn't the local scope protecting the global var?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: you are setting the value of a local variable `var j = a;`, when you use `this.a` you are trying to access a property named `a` of an object referred by `this` both are referring to different values...

Comment: `this` inside function in a browser is `window`.  Global simply means local to the most outer scope which in case of a browser is `window`.

Comment: Thank you.  Doh - yes, shouldn't be using _this_, I'm just over-riding the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go read that! :) That explain precisely how to use this and what is the this!
[Read here! Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Here is the article if the link is dead. (Sorry, the formating is not perfect and the text is very long.)

> Summary
>   A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript
>   compared to other languages. It also has some differences between
>   strict mode and non-strict mode.
>
> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind
>   method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's
>   called.
>
> Syntax this Global context In the global execution context (outside of
>   any function), this refers to the global object, whether in strict
>   mode or not.
>
> console.log(this.document === document); // true
>
> // In web browsers, the window object is also the global object:
>   console.log(this === window); // true
>
> this.a = 37; console.log(window.a); // 37 Function context Inside a
>   function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> Simple call
>
> ```
> function f1(){   return this; }
>
> f1() === window; // global object In this case, the value of this is
> ```
>
> not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value
>   of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.
>
> function f2(){   "use strict"; // see strict mode   return this; }
>
> ```
> f2() === undefined;
> ```
>
> In strict mode, the value of this remains at
>   whatever it's set to when entering the execution context. If it's not
>   defined, it remains undefined. It can also be set to any value, such
>   as null or 42 or "I am not this".
>
> Note: In the second example, this should be undefined, because f2 was
>   called without providing any base (e.g. window.f2()). This feature
>   wasn't implemented in some browsers when they first started to support
>   strict mode. As a result, they incorrectly returned the window object.
>   As an object method
>
> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to
>   the object the method is called on.
>
> In the following example, when o.f() is invoked, inside the function
>   this is bound to the o object.
>
> ```
> var o = {   prop: 37,   f: function() {
>     return this.prop;   } };
>
> console.log(o.f()); // logs 37 Note that this behavior is not at all
> ```
>
> affected by how or where the function was defined. In the previous
>   example, we defined the function inline as the f member during the
>   definition of o. However, we could have just as easily defined the
>   function first and later attached it to o.f. Doing so results in the
>   same behavior:
>
> ```
> var o = {prop: 37};
>
>  function independent() {   return this.prop; }
>
> o.f = independent;
>
> console.log(o.f()); // logs 37 This demonstrates that it matters only
> ```
>
> that the function was invoked from the f member of o.
>
> Similarly, the this binding is only affected by the most immediate
>   member reference. In the following example, when we invoke the
>   function, we call it as a method g of the object o.b. This time during
>   execution, this inside the function will refer to o.b. The fact that
>   the object is itself a member of o has no consequence; the most
>   immediate reference is all that matters.
>
> ```
> o.b = {g: independent, prop: 42}; console.log(o.b.g()); // logs 42
> this on the object's prototype chain
> ```
>
> The same notion holds true for methods defined somewhere on the
>   object's prototype chain. If the method is on an object's prototype
>   chain, this refers to the object the method was called on, as if the
>   method was on the object.
>
> ```
> var o = {f:function(){ return this.a + this.b; }}; var p =
> Object.create(o); p.a = 1; p.b = 4;
>
> console.log(p.f()); // 5 In this example, the object assigned to the
> ```
>
> variable p doesn't have its own f property, it inherits it from its
>   prototype. But it doesn't matter that the lookup for f eventually
>   finds a member with that name on o; the lookup began as a reference to
>   p.f, so this inside the function takes the value of the object
>   referred to as p. That is, since f is called as a method of p, its
>   this refers to p. This is an interesting feature of JavaScript's
>   prototype inheritance.
>
> this with a getter or setter
>
> Again, the same notion holds true when a function is invoked from a
>   getter or a setter. A function used as getter or setter has its this
>   bound to the object from which the property is being set or gotten.
>
> ```
> function modulus(){   return Math.sqrt(this.re * this.re + this.im *
> this.im); }
>
> var o = {   re: 1,   im: -1,   get phase(){
>     return Math.atan2(this.im, this.re);   } };
>
> Object.defineProperty(o, 'modulus', {
>     get: modulus, enumerable:true, configurable:true});
>
> console.log(o.phase, o.modulus); // logs -0.78 1.4142 As a constructor
> ```
>
> When a function is used as a constructor (with the new keyword), its
>   this is bound to new object being constructed.
>
> Note: while the default for a constructor is to return the object
>   referenced by this, it can instead return some other object (if the
>   return value isn't an object, then the this object is returned).
>
> /*  * Constructors work like this:  *  * function MyConstructor(){  * 
>   // Actual function body code goes here.    *   // Create properties on
>   |this| as  *   // desired by assigning to them.  E.g.,  *   this.fum =
>   "nom";  *   // et cetera...  *  *   // If the function has a return
>   statement that  *   // returns an object, that object will be the  *
>   // result of the |new| expression.  Otherwise,  *   // the result of
>   the expression is the object  *   // currently bound to |this|  *   //
>   (i.e., the common case most usually seen).  * }  */
>
> ```
> function C(){   this.a = 37; }
>
> var o = new C(); console.log(o.a); // logs 37
>
>
> function C2(){   this.a = 37;   return {a:38}; }
>
> o = new C2(); console.log(o.a); // logs 38 In the last example (C2),
> ```
>
> because an object was returned during construction, the new object
>   that this was bound to simply gets discarded. (This essentially makes
>   the statement "this.a = 37;" dead code. It's not exactly dead, because
>   it gets executed, but it can be eliminated with no outside effects.)
>
> call and apply
>
> Where a function uses the this keyword in its body, its value can be
>   bound to a particular object in the call using the call or apply
>   methods that all functions inherit from Function.prototype.
>
> ```
> function add(c, d){   return this.a + this.b + c + d; }
>
> var o = {a:1, b:3};
> ```
>
> // The first parameter is the object to use as // 'this', subsequent
>   parameters are passed as  // arguments in the function call
>   add.call(o, 5, 7); // 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16
>
> // The first parameter is the object to use as // 'this', the second
>   is an array whose // members are used as the arguments in the function
>   call add.apply(o, [10, 20]); // 1 + 3 + 10 + 20 = 34 Note that with
>   call and apply, if the value passed as this is not an object, an
>   attempt will be made to convert it to an object using the internal
>   ToObject operation. So if the value passed is a primitive like 7 or
>   'foo', it will be converted to an Object using the related
>   constructor, so the primitive number 7 is converted to an object as if
>   by new Number(7) and the string 'foo' to an object as if by new
>   String('foo'), e.g.
>
> ```
> function bar() {   console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(this));
> }
>
> bar.call(7); // [object Number] The bind method
> ```
>
> ECMAScript 5 introduced Function.prototype.bind. Calling
>   f.bind(someObject) creates a new function with the same body and scope
>   as f, but where this occurs in the original function, in the new
>   function it is permanently bound to the first argument of bind,
>   regardless of how the function is being used.
>
> ```
> function f(){   return this.a; }
>
> var g = f.bind({a:"azerty"}); console.log(g()); // azerty
>
> var o = {a:37, f:f, g:g}; console.log(o.f(), o.g()); // 37, azerty As
> ```
>
> a DOM event handler
>
> When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the
>   element the event fired from (some browsers do not follow this
>   convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than
>   addEventListener).
>
> // When called as a listener, turns the related element blue function
>   bluify(e){   // Always true   console.log(this === e.currentTarget);
>   // true when currentTarget and target are the same object
>   console.log(this === e.target);   this.style.backgroundColor =
>   '#A5D9F3'; }
>
> ```
> // Get a list of every element in the document var elements =
> document.getElementsByTagName('*');
>
> // Add bluify as a click listener so when the // element is clicked
> ```
>
> on, it turns blue for(var i=0 ; i
>   elements[i].addEventListener('click', bluify, false); } In an in–line
>   event handler
>
> When code is called from an in–line handler, its this is set to the
>   DOM element on which the listener is placed:
>
> Show this
>    The above alert shows button. Note however that only the
>   outer code has its this set this way:
>
> Show inner
>   this  In this case, the inner function's this isn't set so it
>   returns the global/window object (i.e. the default object in
>   non–strict mode where this isn't set by the call).